# Show that the equation $y^3+ye^{u+v}+2=0$ has a unique solution $y=f(u,v)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

> Show that the equation $y^3+ye^{u+v}+2=0$ has a unique solution $y=f(u,v)$ defined for all $(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2$. Conclude that $f$ is continuous everywhere.

Let $G(u,v,y)=y^3+ye^{u+v}+2$ then $G:\mathbb R^{2+1}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a $\mathscr C^1$ function and $$D_y(G)=3y^2+e^{u+v}\neq 0$$

OK, then the implicit function theorem ensure there exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $y=f(u,v)$. But how could I get $f$ explicitly? Because there was no point given which I can used to get $\{f_n\}_0^\infty$ converges uniformly to $f$.

---

Another **question** (didn't mention by @ClaudeLeibovici answer) which bother me a lot is,

> How $\mathscr C^1$ of $G$ implies that $f$ is $\mathscr C^1$ in general? I just need the intuition why the fact is true.

---

I always forget to check the first condition of **IFT** that, "$\cdots$ in a neighborhood of the point $(\textbf a,\textbf b)$ where $G(\textbf a,\textbf b)=0$ $\cdots$" Like here the implicit function theorem ensure that there exist a continuous function $f:J\subset\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ centered at $\textbf a\in\mathbf R^2$ such that $y=f(u,v)$. Then how to conclude $f$ is continuous everywhere?

More general question is, how to show such $(\textbf a,\textbf b)$ exist in the context of finding $y=f(u,v)$ defined for all $(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2$ in general (not based on this question)

Comment: The cubic $y^3+Ay-2$ has a unique real root whenever $A≥0$ (as it is a strictly increasing function of $y$).

Comment: Aha, strictly increasing function $\implies$ unique root (real). Thanks @lulu. But how to get that?

Comment: WhyMeasureTheory, what is bothering you precisely? Strictly increasing function implies injective, so if a real root exists, it is unique by injectivity. To get the existence of a real root in the first place, you need to use [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: It's strictly increasing because its derivative is strictly positive.  It goes to $-\infty$ on the left and $+\infty$ on the right, so it must have a root.

Comment: I understand the statement @lulu. I asked how to get $f$ explicitly.

Comment: Why would you want to get $f$ explicitly?

Comment: As everything guarantee there exist such $f$ then why not get it? And the question itself ask for that @lulu

Comment: No, it doesn't.  There are closed formulas for the roots to cubics, but they aren't pretty, and you will have to sort out which root is intended.

Comment: WhyMeasureTheory, knowing something exists doesn't mean we can always write a nice expression for it. In this particular case, you need to solve a depressed cubic equation. You can refer to [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions) to get an expression. However, the question lulu raises is a legit one since even having an expression for something doesn't guarantee that it's useful for anything in practice.

Comment: OK. Maybe I miss your previous comment @Ennar. The thing bother me is the fact that **$G$ is $\mathscr C^1$ implies that $f$ is $\mathscr C^1$** for in general case. I just need the intuition of that fact.

Comment: @lulu can you say something on my last question?, please.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u+v=k$ and solve the cubic equation
$$y^3+e^k\,y+2=0$$
The discriminant
$$\Delta=-4 \left(e^{3 k}+27\right)$$ is always negative; so only one real root given by
$$y=-\frac 2{\sqrt 3} e^{k/2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(3 \sqrt{3} e^{-3
   k/2}\right)\right)$$ This is obtained using the [hyperbolic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root).

Comment: I see. I need to use closed formulas for the roots to cubics equation @ClaudeLeibovici. But I was thinking there should be a sequence of functions which give me the solution 

Comment: Could you say something on my second question? @ClaudeLeibovici